# Using one node in multiple YARN clusters

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have 2 Hadoop clusters, dev and prod. The resources in the dev are under-utilized and I want to somehow use the resources of the nodes in the dev cluster, in the prod cluster (increase the root queue size by the sum of the resources in the dev cluster). The goal is to increase the resources available to the prod root queue without migrating all of the servers in the dev cluster to the prod cluster. I want to avoid any virtualization solutions such as running two VMs or containers on one node.

Is it possible? if yes, how? if no, why?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I think you just want to share resources of one Hadoop cluster with another. Since every Hadoop service is just a Java process with some configuration, you can run services for both clusters on single node. You only have to make sure that each duplicated component has distinct ports, data dirs, logs and so on. Also you have to carefully plan your resource utilization for them.

Comment: I think easier solution will be just migrate several components (nodemanager, datanode) from original cluster to under-utilized. However this can impact performance of migrated components, for example if only YARN nodemanager is migrated, it has to access original cluster for data, which are probably not stored locally.

Answer (score 0):

You in fact can achieve this by registering the NodeManager under the resource manager. just change the configuration to include the NodeManager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).